# How to select radio button in selenium web driver java using text of nearby element in XPath

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I need to select radion button with `id="optProfile"` in 7th tr using text "Internet Users" in td/font tag. I am using below code but it is not working and selecting radio button from 1st tr row. Can anyone help

```
    <html>
<head>
<body onmousedown="infCheckMouseDown(event);" onkeydown="infCheckDownKey(event);" onbeforeunload="INFIEExit();" onload="INFsetInitialFocus();window_onload();CreateScriptingFrames();">
<form action="PEINFCommon.ASP?WCI=Genericcreen&WCE=GenericEvent" onsubmit="return false" name="Genericcreen" method="post">
<table class="TopLevelTable" align="center" width="100%" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="100%">
<table width="100%" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<td width="100%">
<div align="center">
<center>
<table width="98%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" cols="1">
<tbody>
<tr align="center">
<td align="left">
<table width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr height="">
<tr height="">
<tr height="">
<tr height="">
<tr height="">
<tr height="">
<tr height="">
<tr height="">
<tr height="">
<tr height="">
<tr height="">
<tr height="">
<td width="5%">
<input id="optProfile" type="Radio" callfunction="" value="" onblur="ResetScript(this);return true;" onfocus="HighlightScript(this);" onclick="" name="" size="11">
<font class="fLabel"></font>
<br>
<input id="hidCurrentProfile" type="hidden" onblur="ResetScript(this);" onfocus="HighlightScript(this);" value="N" callfunction="" size="11" name="/Root/ACORD/InsuranceSvcRs/nk_ck_com.cc_FetchUserProfileRs/nk_ck_com.cc_SecurityDetails/nk_ck_com.cc_AvailableProfile[12]/nk_ck_com.cc_CurrentProfileInd">
<input id="hidProfile" type="hidden" onblur="ResetScript(this);" onfocus="HighlightScript(this);" value="RACINTER" callfunction="" size="11" name="/Root/ACORD/InsuranceSvcRs/nk_ck_com.cc_FetchUserProfileRs/nk_ck_com.cc_SecurityDetails/nk_ck_com.cc_AvailableProfile[12]/nk_ck_com.cc_ProfileCd">
</td>
<td>
<font class="">Internet Users</font>
</td>
</tr>
<tr height="">
<tr height="">
<tr height="">
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</center>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
</frame>
<frame id="Script" scrolling="Yes" frameborder="0" noresize="">
</frameset>
</html>
```

Comment: please share code with you have written to get and click on that radio button.

Comment: Here it is    WebElement wElement = wDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//font[contains(text(),'Internet Users')]/preceding::tr/td/input[1]"));

Comment: Your question is not clear. From reading comments below, I think what you mean is that you want to click the INPUT (radio) button with `id=optProfile` in the `TR` that contains "Internet Users" in the 2nd `TD`. Please confirm and/or clarify. When you state in the question you are looking for the 7th TR... people take you at your word. If it's not always in the 7th position, don't state it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone here for your help. I really appreciate it.Its working with below code

```
WebElement trs = GlobalVar.wDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//font[text()='Internet Users']/ancestor::tr[1]"));
        trs.findElement(By.id("optProfile")).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `ancestor` instead of `preceding`:

```
//font[text()='Internet Users']/ancestor::tr[1]/td/input[@type='Radio']
```

and it's also a better practice to tell which one of the `tr`-ancestors you want -> `[1]` - since you want the first direct ancestor

Is there a reason why you are not using the id of the radio button?

```
WebElement wElement = wDriver.findElement(By.Id("optProfile"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. It is not working for me and throwing NOsuch elementException .Please could you explain how are we reaching to required radio button using your code so that i can get this worked your code for me. Thank you

Comment: I need 7th tr from top and then first td then radio button

Comment: but if you already know that you definitely need the 7th tr, first td then radio button, why are you searching via the font-text "Internet Users"? Is there a reason?

Comment: Yes because both the tds( radion button and font ) are part of every tr in the html page so basicaly all trs are same except text in font tag. and thats why i am selecting radio button using text of font tag. This text is nothing but a label in front of radio button in my application

Comment: My requirement is to select radio button based on text so everytime 7th row wont work

Comment: @DevkantKrishnatrey try if you can find smaller increments of my xpath -> like "//font[text()='Internet Users']" if that works, then go on to "//font[text()='Internet Users']/ancestor::tr[1]" -> then tell me where selenium cannot find the element any more

Comment: Thanks buddy for your help. Finally it worked. don't know what was i missing earllier

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following XPath

```
//tr[.//font[text()='Internet Users']]//input[@id='optProfile']
```

This xpath looks for the `tr` containing the `font` tag with text "Internet Users" and then navigates to the input tag with id = 'optProfile'

Comment: input tag is not in font tag. font and radio button both are under different td but in same tr

Comment: no.. if you check the XPath, it looks for the `tr` containing the `font` tag. So `tr` is identified and then from `tr` Xpath moves to `input`

Comment: Tried the same but a bit change. //tr[.//font[text()='Internet Users']]//td[1]//input[@id='optProfile']This code is clicking the radio button under very first tr and my code was also doing the same. dont understand why.

Comment: Does your first tr also contain a td>span with text Internet Users ?

Comment: Yes but text is defferret in font tag.Two tds are there in every tr both the tds( radion button and font ) are part of every tr in the html page so basicaly all trs are same except text in font tag. and thats why i am selecting radio button using text of font tag. This text is nothing but a label in front of radio button in my application.My requirement is to select radio button based on text

Comment: I added some dummy html code to test your scenario and it worked for me as expected. There must be some other HTML which is affecting your flow

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preceding` as below-

```
By.xpath("//font[contains(text(),'Internet Users')]/preceding::input[@id='optProfile']")
```

Comment: Its not helping me out

Comment: Are u facing exception - the what?

Comment: Your html is not valid either- no closing input tag Hah!

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this

```
List<WebElement> trs = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("table > tr"));
for (WebElement tr : trs)
{
    List<WebElement> fonts = tr.findElements(By.tagName("font"));
    if (!fonts.isEmpty() && fonts.get(0).getText().trim().equals("Internet Users"))
    {
        tr.findElement(By.id("optProfile")).click();
        break;
    }
}
```

You didn't show the `TABLE` tag in the HTML snippet so you will likely need to be more specific in the initial CSS selector. Basically this code loops through the `TR`s looking for "Internet Users" in the `FONT` tag. Once it finds it, it click the radio button with `id=optProfile`.

If you will post the `TABLE` tag in the HTML snippet I can help with the CSS selector.

---

Edit 1: changed the code to address the case where some `TR`s don't contain `FONT` tags.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated code with table tag in the main post. in the meantime i will try myself using your code

Comment: One more point which i did not notice earlier. Every tr is not having font tag. and its throwing "Unable to ind element with tag name == font "  at the step tr.findElement(By.tagName("font"). How to traverse to those trs only which is having font tag